# an estimated at $1.2 trillion -- grammar?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Example with [a context](http://www.bostonglobe.com/opinion/2014/12/23/ruble-crisis-threatens-putin-hero-like-status/79q8sySYp030cngUp0xvbP/story.html):

> Europe's economy first felt the effect of sanctions as tourist towns in Greece, Czech Republic, and elsewhere remained dormant this summer. Russian tourists and their capital stayed home. Russian investors in Europe also turned tail. But the end is not near. This trouble could soon spill over on to the European Central Bank, thanks to **an estimated** at $1.2 trillion in consumer loans tied to the Russian economy. If bankruptcies begin to rise, we can only imagine how non-performing loans underwritten by European banks will skyrocket.

I don't get that one grammatically. Is the word *estimated* a noun here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is written correctly. I would write:

> This trouble could soon spill over on to the European Central Bank, thanks to **an estimated $1.2 trillion** in consumer loans tied to the Russian economy.

or

> This trouble could soon spill over on to the European Central Bank, thanks to consumer loans **estimated at $1.2 trillion** tied to the Russian economy.

So you then could use *an* or *at*, but not both.